# Which audio interface standard (or API) does macOS use?

Tags: macos, audio

For instance: Windows supports DirectSound & ASIO, Linux supports PulseAudio & Jack, etc.

A basic google search currently does not seem to answer this basic question.

Answer (score 4):

Apple's main low-level Audio Framework / API for macOS 10.0+ is **Core Audio** .

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coreaudio

> Framework
>
> **Core Audio**
>
> Use specialized data types to interact with audio streams, complex buffers, and audiovisual timestamps.
>   SDKs
>
> **Overview**
>
> The Core Audio framework (which is not an umbrella framework for the other services in Core Audio, but rather a peer) declares data types and constants used by other Core Audio interfaces. This framework also includes a handful of convenience functions.

---

Apple actually supports multiple frameworks & APIs, including [AudioUnit](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/audiounit) & [OpenAL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenAL).

Core Audio is actually based on OpenAL.